# Reading VC++ CArchive Binary Format (or Java reading (CObArray))

Tags: java, visual-c++, serialization, mfc, carchive

Is there any clear documentation on the binary formats used to serialize the various MFC data structures?  I've been able to view some of my own classes in a hex editor and use Java's ByteBuffer class to read them in (with automatic endianness conversions, etc).

However, I am currently running into issues while trying to bring over the CObArray data, as there seems to be a rather large header that is opaque to me, and it is unclear how it is persisting object type information.

Is there a set of online documentation that would be helpful for this?  Or some sample Java code from someone that has dealt with this in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MFC ships with source code I would create a test MFC application that serializes a CObArray and step through the serialization code. This should give you all the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with jmatthias: use the MFC source code.

There's also [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32wxt301%28VS.71%29.aspx) on MSDN that may be useful.