# Can I add the CAArchive class to my iPhone project to serialize data? If so, how?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

I have to use the `CAArchiver` class for the serialization of the data coming from the .bin file in my iPhone project (I need to use it in a C++ code snippet). How do I do this?

I have also researched the following link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caz3zy5s(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caz3zy5s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This appears to be used in .NET technology.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CArchive` (as per your link) is part of the Microsoft Foundation Class Library. It's very unlikely that you will find an implementation for them on the iOS platform.

If you need only to provide a kind of serialization, Jigneshs answer is the way to go. If you need to be compatible to other output from `CArchive` then chances are that you will have to implement this by yourself.

Comment: actually i am having .bin format file none of the following line  working for me .can you suggest how can i convert  this bin file to serialize binary file     and  also refer the following link here c++ code for CAArchive is  also given  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz8k76ze.aspx

Comment: If you really have to read in an object generated by CArchive I believe your only way is to take a look a the serialization logic and reimplement it yourself. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369/reading-vc-carchive-binary-format-or-java-reading-cobarray) for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you want:

but there is a class in iphone

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];
```

Where dictionary can be NSObject

```
NSObject *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Where data is a binary i.e. NSData

Using this, I think it will be helpful what you were looking for....

Comment: I need to get the data from the binary file those should get serialize  and CAArchive is used to serialize data  check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz8k76ze.aspx here check syntex for c++

Comment: how would you use it in iphone?

Comment: using c++ code      and     i need   to use   following method CArchive ar( &f, CArchive::load); i don't know how?