# Where can i find how CArchive serialized MFC C++

Tags: qt, mfc, ctime, qdatastream, carchive

The point is I am trying to extract this CTime what was compressed with CArchive into QDateTime using QDataStream. I know that it is not the same, but which is why I am trying to read the raw data out. I have no control over no using CTime CArchive, so ill have to roll with that. I am looking to see how the CTime is being written when using write of CArchive. I am looking for some similar explanations to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933769/21282829 .

I am using this as a reference "
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn002-persistent-object-data-format?view=msvc-170"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn002-persistent-object-data-format?view=msvc-170%22) and can see that 0x8000 means it is using wOldClassTag.

I did reverse engineer and the time I need is 5d960a1b (although not quite, but maybe could be because of the time zone stuff)

```
0x0a    0x00    0x00    0x80    0x1b    0x0a    0x96    0x5d
```

My question is where can I find a description on how CArchive compress the CTime data. I know that 3rd and 4th is 0x00 0x80 is the wOldClassTag, 0x96    0x5d probably date, and 0x1b    0x0a being time. What about the next 4 bytes 0x0a    0x00? does it mean anything?

I tried reading through this Microsoft TN002: Persistent Object Data Format, but it doesnt go to over any detail on how CTime is being serialized. Thank you in advance!

Comment: MFC source code is available, just look there.

Comment: Show the code how you store/retrieve the time to/from CArchive. You probably need an explicit cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you have any information about how the archive was originally stored? Normally you will have to apply the read (>>) operators in the same order.

The relevant source-code files are arccore.cpp, timecore.cpp and afx.inl.

In your case my take is that the archive contains 12 bytes for the object, and this because MFC does some tricks in order to accommodate both 32- and 64-bit times. Check the code of `CArchive& AFXAPI operator <<`. Looks like the first four bytes are that `INT_MIN + 10` prefix, which means that a `__time64_t` (8 bytes) value follows.

Comment: The only infomation i have is that the CArchive write was store with this "ar << m_Time" (CArchive). I will surely look this up just because I cannot do the same with ar >> m_Time (QDataStream)

Comment: @0nePunchMan That sounds odd. `CArchive` and `QDataStream` do not share an implementation. Just because you're using the same syntax doesn't magically make the operator overloads agree on an implementation. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @IInspectable, sorry, I was not being cleared enough. My point is I want to extract the date and time from the serialized CTime (packaged using CArchive). yes, i, at the time, suspected that. I tried it anyways, and it was giving me junk value. So i read the raw data out into char[50 (random# here)] to get the hex value out. which is what you saw up above. That was then i realized that i have to know how carchive package their stuff in order to extract the right information from CTime.

Comment: You have to do the same job I did for `CArchive` (checking the code), but for `QDataStream` this time. If my guesses above are correct, you have to read a uint32 value, and if it's not 0x800A return an error or throw an exception, otherwise read a __time64_t value (or an int64 and cast it to __time64_t), then create the desired object out of it if you want.